# Philosophy of dreams

Tags: reference-request, existence, dreams

According to some eastern teachings (Tantric, Buddhist, etc) it's a good thing to ponder and meditate on dreams:

> **Dream 1**
>
> A person dreams of finding money or gold or any other luxuries. This
>   person keeps gathering all that frenetically until waking up. When
>   that person wakes up realizes that it was impossible to keep that
>   wealth from the dream.
>
> **Dream 2**
>
> A person has a nightmare and fear all his dream. Instead of facing what
>   causes fear decides to wake up from the dream.
>
> **Dream 3**
>
> A person spend all his efforts struggling to get on top of a mountain.
>   The higher this person gets the harder it becomes. This mountain is
>   surrounded by beautiful fruit trees and brooks but the only thought
>   this person has is to climb on the top of the mountain. The person
>   wakes up exhausted and disappointed because there was no way he could
>   have gotten on the top.
>
> **Dream 4**
>
> A person has an ordinary dream but all the sudden
>   realizes that a dream is happening. As this person realizes this
>   decides to take different paths and change things that were meant to
>   happen.

Some of these philosophies compare dreams with real life and death to waking up.  **Are there any other authors or philosophies (western if possible) that emphasize on dreams and how we could learn from them in order to evolve philosophically in life?** (Not interested in interpretation of dreams or similar).

> "What is life? A madness. What is life? An illusion, a shadow, a
>   story. And the greatest good is little enough; for all life is a
>   dream, and dreams themselves are only dreams."
>
> Pedro Calderon de la Barca

Comment: You can see Colin McGinn, [Mindsight : Image Dream Meaning](https://books.google.it/books?id=uf7egmO0qp8C&printsec=frontcover), Harvard UP (2004)

Comment: You say you’re not interested in dream interpretation, but when Freud wrote The Interpretation of Dreams, this was part of a larger research project. He didn’t just want to tell individual clients what their individual dreams meant. Rather, he thought that interpreting dreams (and parapraxes) was a tool for learning about the unconscious and the mechanisms of the mind – again, not just an individual mind, but ‘the mental’ as such. So, he would have agreed that “it's a good thing to ponder and meditate on dreams”. Whether that yields a *philosophy* of mind is a different question, of course.

Comment: Aristotle writes a bit about dreams.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Add that as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: I thing you should see the movie 'Inception'.

Comment: @Overmind and Wizard of Oz, Vanilla Sky, Waking life etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jennifer Windt's [*Dreaming: A Conceptual Framework for Philosophy of Mind and Empirical Research*](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/dreaming) is a recent effort to make dream research bear on questions in the philosophy of mind.

Windt also wrote [a series of blog posts](http://philosophyofbrains.com/2015/07/05/re-mapping-the-concept-of-dreaming.aspx) discussing the main ideas from her book.

Answer (score 0):

Zhuangzi’s Butterfly Dream is a Taoism tale that ponders on dreams [ref here](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Zhuangzi)

> "Once upon a time, I, Zhuangzi, dreamt I was a butterfly, fluttering
>   hither and thither, to all intents and purposes a butterfly. I was
>   conscious only of my happiness as a butterfly, unaware that I was
>   Zhuangzi. Soon I awakened, and there I was, veritably myself again.
>   Now I do not know whether I was then a man dreaming I was a butterfly,
>   or whether I am now a butterfly, dreaming I am a man. Between a man
>   and a butterfly there is necessarily a distinction. The transition is
>   called the transformation of material things."